# Помогите доработать jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, wordpress

Доброго времени суток.
У меня проблема с  jQuery Fancybox. В шаблоне он настроен кодом и имеет вот такой вид.

```
/**************************************************************************/
/*  Fancybox                                                              */
/**************************************************************************/

a.fancybox-overlay
{
    display:block;
    border-bottom:none !important;
}

a.fancybox-overlay:hover
{
    position:relative;
}

.fancybox-overlay img,
.fancybox-overlay span
{
    display:block;
}

.fancybox-overlay span
{
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    opacity:0;
    width:240px;
    height:160px;
    #display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-image:url('images/thumb_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay span,
.fancybox-overlay:hover span
{
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fancybox-overlay:hover span
{
    opacity:1;
    #display:block;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    #filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Но на деле она не работает корректно.
фотографии выглядят здорово:

[image: Пример неоткрытой картинки]

но не закрываются:

[image: Пример раскрытой картинки]

единственный выход их закрыть, обновить страницу. Сам я в коде не очень шарю, может кто-то поможет?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего нужно расширить функцию вызова свойствами (closeBtn и/или closeClick).